# When my widget is clicked, I want to show an input box. Is the way to do this creating a DialogFragment with a single-purpose Activity to display it?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

My goal is to pop up a simple input box when a user clicks on my widget.

Most tutorials out there seem to use showDialog(), but that is apparently deprecated.

I have a solution that is semi-working, but it seems surprisingly complicated for such a simple task.

In the widget's `onUpdate` method I'm calling `setOnClickPendingIntent` with the intent set to launch my FragmentActivity TextDialogActivity.

In TextDialogActivity's `onCreate` method, I call `new TextDialog` and then its `show` method.

TextDialog extends a DialogFragment, and its layout XML defines an EditText, and in its `onCreateDialog` method I add in positive and negative buttons, setting listeners to them to either capture the input on Okay or `finish` the activity on Cancel.

**Is this a beginner hack, or is this really the way that a simple text input box is created in Android?**

Also, I said that it's only semi-working, because the activity is popping up a background over the home screen, rather than the input dialog simply overlaying the home screen. I assume this is a side effect of my beginner hack, but if this is in fact the correct approach, what am I doing wrong that is causing that? I would have thought by not calling `setContentView` in TextDialogActivity, that wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final EditText et=new EditText(MainActivity.this);              
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
              .setTitle("Title")
              .setView(et)
              .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //enter your code
                }
            })
              .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                    //enter your code
                }
            })
              .create()
              .show();
```